# Session variable working in IE and Safari, but not Chrome, Opera or Firefox?

Tags: php

I'm setting a session variable from a log in page ($_SESSION['login']). I've tested thoroughly, the variable is definitely being created and the correct value is being stored ($_SESSION['login'] = '1'), but the variable isn't recognized in the next page using Chrome, Opera or Firefox - oddly enough, the same script works as I expect in Safari and Internet  Explorer.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated - I've been trying to figure this one out for a while and just can't get it - I'm at a complete loss here.

Here's the step by step -

```
<?php
// log in page
// if logged in successfully set the session variable

session_start();

if (// log in credentials good) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = '1';
    header('location:inside_page.php');

    // echo $_SESSION['login'] ;
    // ----------------------
    // commenting out the redirect and echoing
    // the session variable works as expected
    // in IE, Safari, Chrome, Opera and Firefox
}

?>
```

Here's my Check_login class - it get's instantiated in the next page (inside_page.php) -

class:

```
<?php

if (! defined('EXT')){ exit('Invalid file request'); }

class Check_login { 
    private $login = null ;

    function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $this->login = $_SESSION['login'];
        if ($this->login != '1') {
            header('location:../index.php');
        }

        // $login = $this->login ;
        // echo $login ;
        // $session = $_SESSION['login'];
        // echo $session ;
        // ----------------------
        // commenting out the redirect and echoing the
        // session variable shows 1 in IE and Safari, but
        // empty in Chrome, Opera and Firefox
    }

}

?>
```

page (inside_page.php):

```
<?php

require('../lib/Check_login.php');

session_start();

$login = new Check_login;

?>
```

Again, any help at all would be really awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out - I can't say that I understand WHY this is the case, but this is what fixed my problem. In my log in page, after verifying the login credentials I set the session variable 'login' to 1 and then explicitly redirected to another page. I realized after testing, that using a relative URL for my redirection fixed the problem.

My original post didn't even illustrate the URL because I didn't think it was necessary, but here's where the problem was -

```
<?php
// log in page
// if logged in successfully set the session variable

session_start();

if (// log in credentials good) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = '1';
    header('location:https://www.somedomain.com/inside_page.php'); // *** PROBLEM
}

?>
```

By setting the location relatively, my problem went away -

```
<?php
// log in page
// if logged in successfully set the session variable

session_start();

if (// log in credentials good) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = '1';
    header('location:inside_page.php'); // *** FIX
}

?>
```

I double-checked, and the secure connection definitely wasn't the problem, it was the explicit URL.

Using a relative location my session variable showed up in the next page in Internet Explorer, Safari, Chrome, Opera and Firefox. Using an explicit location it showed up in IE and Safari, BUT NOT in CHROME, OPERA and FIREFOX.

You can recreate this easily and try it for yourself -

```
<?php

// ------- page_one.php -------

session_start();

$_SESSION['val'] = '1';

header("location:http://www.somedomain.com/page_two.php") ;
// header("location:page_two.php") ;

?>

<?php

// ------- page_two.php -------

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['login'] != '1') {
    echo 'false' ;
} else {
    echo 'true' ;
}

?>
```

Hopefully this saves someone else some time (and headache).

Answer (score 0):

Move `session_start()` above your require statement in inside_page.php.

Sessions should be initiated at the very beginning of a script and almost always before includes.

Comment: <: ( - Didn't fix the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: @canoebrain Are you using cookies at all? And is this your entire script currently?

Comment: No, I haven't posted my entire script, I'm actually calling a handful of classes and doing other things, but I've boiled this down to exactly where the problem is arising. If I create a page, set my session variable equal to one, then redirect to the next page where I call my class (which is exactly the class I'm using) I have this problem. I'd be tempted to think it's some setting in Chrome, but it happens in Opera and Firefox too... oh, and I'm not using any cookies at all.

Comment: Scratch that Baez - I'm such an idiot - the same thing doesn't happen if I completely isolate this stuff, it has to be something I'm doing in another class or something. I'll go back again through EVERYTHING to try and fix it myself again. Thanks for your time Baez, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to integrate digitalaccesspass (DAP) onto a PHP5.5 server (breaking in all Webkit/Blink browsers, so breaking logins for Chrome, Safari, and Opera), and a constellation of these changes helped.

- I made sure the very first line in the authenticator was `session_start()`
- Right before all redirects (`header("Location:")` calls) I added `session_write_close()`.
- The redirects were edited to be relative paths, rather than absolute.

For people stumbling across this via Google, if you're hitting this with DAP, make these changes in /dap/authenticate.php

Answer (score 0):

My PHP session was also not working in Chrome.

I found that the PHPSESSID cookie path was not synced between my pages despite each page using simply `session_start()` to initialize each session.

Adding this line above `session_start()` to the page on which I wrote data to the session solved the problem:

```
session_set_cookie_params(600, '/');
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php